# How to map a column to JSONB instead of JSON, with Doctrine and Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my project I'm using Doctrine doctrine 2.5.4/postgres 9.5. I'm trying to add a `jsonb` field using YAML:

```
fields:
  obj: json_array
```

This gets interpreted as a `json` column type (and not `jsonb`).  The specification notes about picking up `json` or `jsonb`:

> Chosen if the column definition contains the jsonb option inside the platformOptions attribute array and is set to true.

But `platformOptions` doesn't seem to work (tried to add it below obj, at the top... with no success). How can I add a `jsonb` field?

Comment: Seems like there is no way to do that (just checked in the source for the same doctrine/dbal version)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is supported by doctrine/dbal v2.6+ (it requires PHP 7.1). All you need to do is use `json_array` and set `options={"jsonb"=true}` I tested this on doctrine/dbal v2.6.3

This is what it looks like in PHP format:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json_array",nullable=true,options={"jsonb"=true})
 */
  private $details;
```

and it creates a query such as (for an existing table):

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD details JSONB NOT NULL;
```

More details about type mapping can be found at Doctrine [mapping matrix.](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/docs/en/reference/types.rst#mapping-matrix)

Comment: It worked! Can you give me more document about `options` values? I can't not find anything about `"jsonb"=true` in official document.

Comment: @Geany I have added the link to mapping matrix to the answer. But json_array is deprecated... :)

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen use  `type="json", options={"jsonb": true}`

Comment: @Geany Only for PostgreSQL. In source code https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/3.1.x/src/Platforms/PostgreSQL94Platform.php#L1218 `PostgreSQL100Platform extends PostgreSQL94Platform` `if (!empty($column['jsonb'])) { return 'JSONB';} return 'JSON';`

Comment: even cleaner approach with PHP >= 8.0 and attributes would be `#[ORM\Column(type: Types::JSON, nullable: true, options: ['jsonb' => true])]`

Answer (score 1):

Use [boldtrn/jsonb-bundle](https://github.com/boldtrn/JsonbBundle), it provides a `jsonb` doctrine type as well as custom functions to access the special operators provided by the PostgreSQL `jsonb` data type.